# Remote COM server instantiation

Tags: c#, com, rpc, dcom

I have a COM interface to start and use a program. This works great on a local machine. Is there a possibility to start that program on another machine, through the network without installing other software on it or making changes to the program?

Comment: Google "configure DCOM".  Most stuff you'll find is badly out of date.  And undiagnosable config problems are common.

Answer (score 2):

DCOM though you'll need to configure security.

In C# you can instantiate the object remotely like so:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Acme.Server", "remotepc", true));
```

So to instantiate the VB Regex library (so that it runs elsewhere)

```
dynamic re = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VBScript.RegExp", "remotepc", true));
re.IgnoreCase = true;   //Check that we can set properties
re.Pattern = "^A";
var chk = (re.Execute("Apple").Count > 0) ? "ok" : "failed";
Console.WriteLine(chk);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use COM+. You can [create a COM+ application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687759(VS.85).aspx) on the remote machine, then [create an installation package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680546(VS.85).aspx), and finally [deploy the application proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679498(VS.85).aspx) on your local machine.  The result will allow you to use the COM server just as if it was installed locally, without having to change your code.